# Tree traversal (preorder,inorder,postorder) print result change

Tags: c, tree

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <memory.h>  

void preorder(char tree[], int i)    
{  
   if(tree[i] != '\0')  
   {  
        printf("%c", tree[i]);
        preorder(tree, i*2);  
        preorder(tree, i*2+1);  
  }  
}  
void inorder(char tree[], int i)  
{  
   if(tree[i] != '\0')  
   {  
        inorder(tree, i*2);  
        printf("%c", tree[i]);  
        inorder(tree, i*2+1);  
  }  
}  
void postorder(char tree[], int i) 
{  
   if(tree[i] != '\0')  
   {  
        postorder(tree, i*2);  
        postorder(tree, i*2+1);  
        printf("%c", tree[i]);  
  }  
}  
void main()  
{  

   char ArrayTree[36] = { 0,'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K',0, };  
   printf("\n preorder : ");  
   preorder(ArrayTree, 1);  
   printf("\n inorder: ");  
   inorder(ArrayTree, 1);  
   printf("\n postorder: ");  
   postorder(ArrayTree, 1);  
   getchar();  
}
```

Current Print result

preorder : ABDHIEJKCFG  /
inorder: HDIBJEKAFCG      /
postorder: HIDJKEBFGCA   /

But I want to print like this

preoder : ABDHEIJCFGK  /
inorder : HDBIEJAFCGK  /
postorder : HDIJEBFKGCA  /

[Binary Tree image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0Ycj.jpg)

How to change it?

Comment: Why do you tag it as "Java" when it clearly isn't Java code?

Comment: Sorry, I forgotten delete Java tag I've created before.

Comment: array you posted and the tree image is not related

Comment: Oh...then, I wrote the wrong code..... How to fix it for relate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks correct but your data is wrong. It doesn't represent the tree in your diagram. For example, the right sibling of `'H'` should be 0 (or NULL).

A corrected array looks like:

```
char ArrayTree[32] = { 0,'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H',0,'I','J',0,0,0,'K' };
```

The size only needs to be 32 to contain a complete tree of height 5 (plus the unused 0 index).